# AWS - ELB - Routing http/https traffic to a custom port of EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I've an application up and running on and EC2 instance at port 5000. I've been trying to add either application load balancer or classic load balancer to route my traffic to this application.

Until at this point, the application is available over HTTP protocol at http://example.com:5000/.

So my question is, what steps I need to do to make this application available without typing the port number in the URL.

Please note that I want to have multiple instances of the app up and running at different ports and are mapped to different subdomains.

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html

Comment: The application load balancer has a listener, and the port is defined when you set up the listener. So you just need to create an http or https listener on port 80 or 443 that in turn forward the request to the target

Answer (score 2):

So after spending couple of hours and going through the documentation again, this is how it worked for me.

1. Created an Application load balancer
2. Created a `Target Group` that listens on `HTTP` port `80`.
3. In this target group, selected the ec2 instance and registered it on port `5000`
4. In the load balancer section, added two listeners. One for HTTP and one for HTTPs. Added default action to forward all traffic to that `Target Group` that was created in step 2. and it all worked for me.

The important bit was to set up the Target Group in step 2 and 3 correctly. I was creating two target groups for http and https separately which was incorrect. I just had to creat one target group for http only.